# Passing variables into SLOTs - QSignalMapper

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

[image]

I am trying to use the same image upload function for both the images upload.

So on click of the Upload button, I need to pass either self.UploadStudentPhoto or self.UploadParentsPhoto to self.UploadFile() function, corresponding to which button is pressed.

As we cannot pass a variable into a SLOT, so I am trying to use QSignalMapper, as below.

```
self.UploadStudentPhoto = QLineEdit() #Student Photo location
self.UploadParentsPhoto = QLineEdit() #Parents Photo location
self.ParentsImage = None

self.SignalMapper = QSignalMapper()
self.connect(self.ButtonUpload1,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.SignalMapper, SLOT("map()"))
self.connect(self.ButtonUpload2,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.SignalMapper,SLOT("map()"))

self.SignalMapper.setMapping(self.ButtonUpload1, self.UploadStudentPhoto)
self.SignalMapper.setMapping(self.ButtonUpload2, self.UploadParentsPhoto)
```

But I am not sure about the below line where I need to pass SIGNAL("mapped()") to a function I wrote for file upload. How should I write the below line:

```
self.connect(self.SignalMapper,SIGNAL("mapped()"), self, self.UploadFile)
```

upload file function is below:

```
def UploadFile(self, ImagePath, ImageLabel):
    dir = os.path.dirname(".")
    formats = ["*.%s" % unicode(format).lower()\
        for format in QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()]
    self.fname = unicode(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Image",dir,"Image (%s)" % " ".join(formats)))
    print self.fname
    ImagePath.setText(self.fname)
    ImagePath.selectAll()
    ImageLabel = QImage()
    ImageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(ImageLabel))
```

I saw many QSignalMapper examples but I am not sure how exactly the variable is passed.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, It can pass a variable into connect  & SLOT, by use `partial` module in python;

For my opinion, I suggest use 'simple' (I think)  to implement, I will show you in code below;

```
from functools import partial
.
.
.
        self.StudentPhoto = QLabel() # I know you have this.
        self.ParentsPhoto = QLabel() # I know you have this too.
        self.UploadStudentPhoto = QLineEdit()
        self.UploadParentsPhoto = QLineEdit()
        self.connect(self.ButtonUpload1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), partial(self.UploadFile, self.UploadStudentPhoto, self.StudentPhoto))
        self.connect(self.ButtonUpload2, SIGNAL("clicked()"), partial(self.UploadFile, self.UploadParentsPhoto, self.ParentsPhoto))
.
.
.
    def UploadFile(self, ImagePath, ImageLabel):
        dir = os.path.dirname(".")
        formats = ["*.%s" % unicode(format).lower()\
            for format in QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()]
        self.fname = unicode(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Image",dir,"Image (%s)" % " ".join(formats)))
        print self.fname
        ImagePath.setText(self.fname)
        ImagePath.selectAll()
.
.
.
```

---

**Example reference** : http://www.learnpython.org/en/Partial_functions

**Official reference** : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html

---

Regards,